# Polymer icons within elements not rendering in Firefox or Safari (Rails app with Emcee gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, svg, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to integrate Polymer into a Rails 4 app via the [Emcee gem](https://github.com/ahuth/emcee). I can't get icons *within* web components (e.g., icon-"search" within paper-icon-button) to render in Firefox. Icons by themselves will work though. Also, this problem does not occur in Chrome. I suspect a pipeline issue. Open to clean workarounds if necessary.

application.html (manifest for Polymer components folders/files)

```
 *= require polymer/polymer
 *= require core-header-panel/core-header-panel
 *= require core-toolbar/core-toolbar
 *= require paper-button/paper-button
 *= require paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button
 *= require core-icon/core-icon
 *= require core-icons/core-icons
 *= require font-roboto/roboto
 *= require paper-shadow/paper-shadow
```

application.js (manifest for js folder/file; first on the list is only one relevant to Polymer)

```
//= require webcomponentsjs/webcomponents
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.html.erb (html layout with links to pull-in application manifests shown above)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= yield(:title) %> | RailsWithPolymerTest </title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= html_import_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body class="<%= controller.controller_name %>">
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= render 'shared/flash_alert' %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**It looks like the necessary files are being served to the browser unless I'm missing some dependency in the manifest(s)**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/morris.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/choices.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/question_formats.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/question_sets.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/questions.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/respondents.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/responses.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/sessions.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/users.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<script src="/assets/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<script src="/assets/jquery.turbolinks.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<script src="/assets/raphael.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<script src="/assets/morris.min.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<script src="/assets/chart_refresh.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<script src="/assets/nav.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<script src="/assets/questions.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/polymer/layout.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<style shim-shadowdom-css="">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/polymer/polymer.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<style>
<link rel="import" href="/assets/core-focusable/core-focusable.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/paper-button/paper-button-base.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/paper-button/paper-button.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/core-meta/core-meta.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/core-iconset/core-iconset.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/core-icon/core-icon.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<style>
<link rel="import" href="/assets/core-iconset-svg/core-iconset-svg.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/core-icons/core-icons.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/font-roboto/roboto.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&lang=en">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/application.html?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
```

**But core-icon (all of below; as excerpted from within a paper-icon-button) is grayed-out in browser console:**

```
<core-icon id="icon" icon="{{icon}}" src="{{src}}" relative="" aria-label="menu" role="img">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="pointer-events: none; display: block;" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" fit="">
<g>
<path d="M3 18h18v-2h-18v2zm0-5h18v-2h-18v2zm0-7v2h18v-2h-18z">
</g>
</svg>
</core-icon>
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this exact issue, and fixed it by adding these global styles:

```
core-icon-button {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 7px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
html core-icon {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  fill: currentcolor;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 24px;
}
```

After adding those, the icons worked fine in both Firefox and Safari for me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I look forward to testing it out once I complete the current task of  wrestling my paginated JS charts back from Foundation. @jamesrogers10

Comment: Yes! Strangely, it worked with the paper-icon-button for me, but not with core-icon-button. Kind of expected the other way around if anything. Cool nonetheless though! Thanks, man! At least I get some satisfaction for a weekend spent mucking around with Polymer. @jamesrogers10

Answer (score 1):

If it works on chrome and does not work on Firefox, it seems like it might be an incompatibility issue.

You might want to take a look at Polymers ["Browser Compatibility"](https://www.polymer-project.org/resources/compatibility.html) chart.  And also, just in case, to see that you have the most recent version of Firefox.

Also, what version of Polymer you are using? they have just gone from version 0.4.0 to 0.5.x, you might want to look into that. Version 0.4.0 might not have the polyfills needed for compatibility with Firefox.

Comment: I think it's an 'SVG not rendering' issue, perhaps due to some of the polyfills not working properly. I've seen the chart and from my understanding, if polyfills work, then it should be good on any evergreen browser of which FF is included (so, yes, latest version). I'm using Polymer 0.5.x, which uses the webcomponents.js as opposed to prior, which used platform.js, so I've accounted for this in my imports. Thanks for the note and please throw an additional ideas my way. @germ13

Comment: @Benco dont know if this will help, i tried rendering the svg you posted above @ the site http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_svg_ex . I put your svg (sans core-icon) on the left hand text panel.  Then i removed everything except what was in the path tag, got hamburger icon.  Just trying to give you some insight.

Comment: Yeah, while fussing around with the implementation, I can get the lone SVG's to render on the page, but never inside the intended/parent element, e.g., if I use something like core-icon-button the SVG will render outside of the button and much too large. I think it's some conflict with Polymer's polyfill code and Rails pipeline. It works in Chrome (no surprise). Does not work in FF or Safari. @germ13